# How to fix "NoReverseMatch at /polls/" with "'polls' is not a registered namespace" error?

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-urls

My mysite/urls.py is this

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And, my polls/urls.py is

```
from .import views
from django.conf.urls import url

from django.contrib.auth.views import login

urlpatterns= [
    url(r'^$',views.index, name= "index"),
    #127.0.0.1/polls
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name= "detail"),
    #127.0.0.1/polls/1
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results$', views.results, name="results"),
    #127.0.0.1/polls/1/results
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote$', views.vote, name="vote"),
    #127.0.0.1/polls/1/vote
    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'polls/login.html'})
]
```

The error I am getting is there is no registered namespace as polls. Do help.

Comment: post your polls urls.py file

Comment: i have edited the post with polls/urls.py. Do check it and help.

Comment: what is the url that you are trying to access?

Comment: i guess the real error comes from settings.py file? have you added polls to the installed apps section?

Answer (score 1):

In you mysite/urls.py file change this line:

```
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
```

to this line:

```
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace='polls')),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

polls/urls.py should have

```
app_name = 'polls' #This line is missing
urlpatterns= [
    url(r'^$',views.index, name= "index"),
    #127.0.0.1/polls
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name= "detail"),
    #127.0.0.1/polls/1
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results$', views.results, name="results"),
    #127.0.0.1/polls/1/results
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote$', views.vote, name="vote"),
    #127.0.0.1/polls/1/vote
    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'polls/login.html'})
]
```

Comment: It worked but it required name in place of namespqce